# How to include a user's name in a random message [Python]

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I am new to coding. I want my bot to respond to a user command with a randomized message where the **location of their name in the message varies**.

```
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    responses = ["hi, {ctx.author.name}！",
                 "{ctx.author.name}, how are you?",
                 "Good day, {ctx.author.name}, how's the weather there?"]
    await ctx.send(f'{random.choice(responses)}')
```

This is what happens when I deploy the bot:

```
/hello
hi, {ctx.author.name}!

/hello
{ctx.author.name}, how are you?
```

However, I want the bot to respond with the user's name, for instance

```
/hello
hi, Bob!

/hello
Bob, how are you?
```

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use f-strings

```py
responses = [
    f"hi, {ctx.author.name}！",
    f"{ctx.author.name}, how are you?",
    f"Good day, {ctx.author.name}, how's the weather there?"
]
```